# Quiero traer la información de los académicos que no estén en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos con las tablas

- USUARIO,
- ACADEMICO,
- INFORMACION_PERSONAL,
- SECCION.

Quiero traer la información de todos los académicos que no estén en la tabla SECCION y que sean usuarios activos usando la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT ACADEMICO.id_usuario,INFORMACION_PERSONAL.nombre,INFORMACION_PERSONAL.aPaterno,INFORMACION_PERSONAL.aMaterno 
   FROM ACADEMICO 
NATURAL JOIN INFORMACION_PERSONAL 
NATURAL JOIN USUARIO 
  WHERE USUARIO.estado=1 
    AND ACADEMICO.id_usuario NOT IN (SELECT id_usuario FROM SECCION)
```

Pero me manda campos en blanco aunque me debería regresar dos.

Las tablas están conformadas de la siguiente manera:
[image: Descripción de tablas]
¿Alguien que me pueda orientar?

Comment: Hola @René. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías mostrarnos cómo es la estructura de las tablas? ¿Qué columnas tienen? ¿No hay otra columna en común es además de `id_usuario`? ¿Los registros que debería devolver están activos? Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con la descripción de tablas.

Comment: Quizás otro vea algo que yo no estoy viendo, pero no encuentro ningún error. La consulta está bien. Ejemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bece/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que probablemente tienes valores `null` en la columna `id_usuario` de tu tabla `SECCION`. Tu estructura indica que esa columna permite valores `null`.

De ser el caso, con que tengas tan solo un registro con `id_usuario = null` en la tabla `SECCION`, la claúsula `NOT IN ()` causará que tu consulta no te devuelva ningún resultado.

Por ejemplo, si tomo prestado el [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bece/1/0) de Mariano en su comentario, y lo modifico para agregar un registro en la tabla `SECCION` con `id_usuario = null`, verás que la consulta ya no funciona correctamente: [SQLFiddle que no funciona debido a un valor `null`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08aab1/1).

El problema es que las evaluaciones booleanas con valores `null` nunca evaluan a `true`. De modo que esta parte de tu consulta:

```
AND ACADEMICO.id_usuario NOT IN (SELECT id_usuario FROM SECCION)
```

... si se topa con un registro donde `SECCION.id_usuario` es `null`, la condición equivale a:

```
AND ACADEMICO.id_usuario <> null
```

... lo que no evaluará a `true`.

Para evitar este problema muy sutil, te sugiero que uses `NOT EXISTS` en vez de `NOT IN`.

Yo escribiría la consulta de esta manera (nota que yo prefiero evitar los natural joins, pero ese detalle no es importante en este caso):

```
 SELECT a.id_usuario,
        i.nombre,
        i.aPaterno,
        i.aMaterno 
   FROM ACADEMICO a 
   JOIN INFORMACION_PERSONAL i
     ON i.id_usuario = a.id_usuario
   JOIN USUARIO u
     ON u.id_usuario = a.id_usuario
  WHERE u.estado = 1 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                      FROM SECCION s
                     WHERE s.id_usuario = a.id_usuario)
```

[SQLFiddle que funciona bien a pesar del valor `null`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08aab1/3).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!